# What is the equivilent of UIImage *anImage in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, objective-c, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

In Objective-C I can do the following and pass a UIImage (image) object into a function, such as this:

```
+ (void)saveImageLocally:(NSString *)barcode theImage:(UIImage *)anImage;
```

What is the equivilent in C#?

This question pertains to Windows Phone programming.

Comment: Yes, for Windows Phone, sorry I didn't include that in the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need [`System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) or one of its ancestors (`BitmapSource` or `ImageSource`).

If you want to easily access image's pixels, you need [`System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
void saveImageLocalley(string barcode, System.Drawing.Image theImage)
```

Normaly we use `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, it's a subclass of `Image`.

Comment: System.Drawing.Bitmap isn't available on Windows Phone.